# Unable to pass value to controller from view through viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty sure my brain is friend and this is something I'm going to laugh at tomorrow morning, but unfortunately I'm stuck on this portion and am asking for assistance.

I have a ViewModel:

```
public class HousingDetailsViewModel : AppViewModel
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public List<string> units { get; set; }
    public List<AvailableHousing> availableHousings { get; set; }
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public OccupiedHousing currentHousing { get; set; }
    public OccupiedHousing newHousing;

    public HousingDetailsViewModel(int? id)
    {
            units = db.AvailableHousings.OrderBy(ah => ah.Unit).Select(h => h.Unit).Distinct().ToList();
            availableHousings = db.AvailableHousings.Where(h => h.Available == true).OrderBy(h => h.Bed)
                                                                                    .OrderBy(h => h.Room).ToList();
            currentHousing = db.OccupiedHousing.Include(o => o.AvailableHousing)
                                               .Include(o => o.Person).Where(o => o.PersonID == id && o.CurrentHousing == true).FirstOrDefault();
            person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            newHousing = new OccupiedHousing();
    }
}
```

My controller methods for this view:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    return View(new HousingDetailsViewModel(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Move(OccupiedHousing newHousing, int? personID)
{
    newHousing.PersonID = personID;
    newHousing.DateArrived = DateTime.Now;
    newHousing.CurrentHousing = true;
    newHousing.AvailableHousingID = housingID;
    db.OccupiedHousings.Add(newHousing);
    db.SaveChanges();


    return RedirectToAction("Index", new HousingViewModel());
}
```

And my form works fine for all of my fields except for 1, and that's the AvailableHousingID. I've tried setting a hidden value. I put a breakpoint where I set the value of the hidden field and I watched it change, but it didn't make it to the controller. So I changed it to a form submission and tried to catch it as a routevalue and that didn't work either. I'm at a loss, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT: Adding View**

```
@model AppName.ViewModels.HousingDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Housing Details";
}

@Html.BeginForm("Move", "Housing", new { personID = @Model.person.ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { })
<script>
    function setID(id) {
        $('#HiddenHousingID').val(id);
        $('#HiddenSubmit').click();
    }
</script>
<h2>Housing Details</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 container">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/77CCDD/66BBCC" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <h4>@Model.person.ComboName</h4>
            <h4>@Model.currentHousing.AvailableHousing.Unit - @Model.currentHousing.AvailableHousing.Room - @Model.currentHousing.AvailableHousing.Bed</h4>
            <h4>@Model.person.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString()</h4>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newHousing.AvailableHousingID, new { id = "HiddenHousingID", name = "newHousing.AvailableHousingID")}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var unit in Model.units)
    {
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="panel-title">
                        @unit
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table id="MoveHousingTable" class="table table table-condensed table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Available Housing
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var housing in Model.availableHousings.Where(h => h.Unit == unit))
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @housing.Room -
                                        @housing.Bed
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" value="Select" name="select" onclick="setID(@housing.ID)" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<input type="submit" class="hidden" id="HiddenSubmit">
}
```

Comment: can you also share the view

Comment: (1) View model should NEVER contain database access code (2) View models should never contain data models when editing. (3) You passing a `HousingDetailsViewModel` to the view so your post method needs to be `public ActionResult Move(HousingDetailsViewModel model)` (4) You do not appear to have a parameterless constructor so the `DefaultModelBinder` will throw an exception once you fix point 3

Comment: @Usman, I have updated to show the view. I'm showing the use of the BeginForm where I DO NOT use the housingID parameter for the Move method. I guess I should have taken it out above.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for that information. I am just moving to MVC from WebForms and this is how I was instructed. Now that I know, I will work on moving the access code to the models. I did however, change the OccupiedHousing Type in the Move method to the ViewModel and added a parameterless constructor to the ViewModel and it's the same issue.

Comment: Your view is not really making any sense (you dnt even have any editable controls), but in the POST method `model.newHousing.AvailableHousingID` will contain the value that you script sets.

Comment: I'm not using the form to allow for editing. The user selects a person in one view, they are brought to this view to select an available room. It's just a button click. In hindsight, I could have probably done this in a partial view...

Comment: Then you using the wrong approach. Why is it not just a link?

Answer (score 0):

For the route :

```
@Html.BeginForm("Move", "Housing", new { personID = @Model.person.ID , housingID=  @Model.newHousing.AvailableHousingID}, FormMethod.Post, new { })
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to take the housingID parameter out of the Move method. When I use the hidden, I'm not using the parameter as hiddenfor is, at least I thought, supposed to handle it.

Comment: Then u should follow stephen's view/idea - it is right what he is suggesting. .